# How to allow only one class to access a method from another class?

Tags: ruby

I would like to have something like this:

```
class A
  def only_B_can_call_me
    'called_by_B'
  end
end

class B
  def do_stuff(a)
    a.only_B_can_call_me
  end
end

class C
  def do_stuff(a)
    a.only_B_can_call_me # how to forbid it?
  end
end

B.new.do_stuff(A.new) # => 'called_by_B'
C.new.do_stuff(A.new) # => it should not be allowed!!! but how to do it?
```

One way to do this is to make `only_B_can_call_me` a private method and use `a.send(:only_B_can_call_me)` inside B. OK, it works. But I could be tempted in doing the same thing inside C... so, I think it is not a good approach. Is there any other way to do this? (Allow a method be accessed just by instances of a specific class.)

(I know that ultimately it is always possible to access any method from anywhere using `send`. But I want to keep myself away from `send` in this case.)

Comment: Which is your actual Ruby version?

Comment: I am currently on ruby 2.4.1

Comment: Well, I hope my solution can help you, I'm glad to help. I tryed and it works https://repl.it/Mmt5/6 you can see it there

Comment: Djunzu, could you add the real example of the code? I need to know why are you giving "a" as parameter of do_stuff method? because if you check my updated answer, you will find it's not necessary

Comment: @DamianLattenero, sorry, can't give you the real code. `a` don't have to be a parameter;  it could be created inside the method as well. The point is "only B can call me". something similar to `friend` in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no clear solutions. If B can do it, so can C. Unlike some other languages, ruby doesn't have "internal" or "package" visibility modifier, which could help you if A and B were in the same "package", but C was external. If the method is private, even B has to use `send`. If it's public, C can just call it. B is not a subclass of A in your example, so `protected` modifier doesn't apply.

One dirty-dirty way would be to check `caller` in `only_B_can_call_me`. It returns the entire callstack. So you can check if it is, indeed, B or reject otherwise. But this is super-fragile and totally not recommended.

Comment: This is a perfect explain of why... Thanks for sharing and show me my errors, you rules! is a plus one

Comment: Sergio, as you know a lot more about Ruby, I will really appreciate if you can check my updated answer, and comment again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could do with help of @Sergio Tulentsev:

```
class A 
  def only_B_can_call_me(b) 
    return unless b.class == B # here you are asking
    'called_by_B' 
  end 
end

class B
  def do_stuff(a)
    a.only_B_can_call_me(self) # how to forbid it? ask if self is B
  end
end

class C
  def do_stuff(a)
    a.only_B_can_call_me(self) # how to forbid it? ask if self is B
  end
end
```

Other way is using subclass:

```
class A 
  def only_B_can_call_me
    'called_by_B' 
  end 
end

class B < A
  def do_stuff
    self.only_B_can_call_me
  end
end

class C
  def do_stuff
    self.only_B_can_call_me # how to forbid it?, like this C hasn't the method, B does
  end
end



puts(B.new.do_stuff) # => 'called_by_B'
puts(C.new.do_stuff) # => it should not be allowed!!! but how to do it?
```

Comment: `self.class` will never be `B.class`

Comment: `self.class` is `C` and `B.class` is `Class`. They are never going to be equal.

Comment: @DamianLattenero: yah, now try the same in `B`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I wanted to do this, but I made a huge mistake https://repl.it/Mmt5/1

Comment: What prevents C from calling `__only_B_can_call_me__`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Nothing at all, it is just more clear that you shouldn't

Comment: @DamianLattenero: well, if it's just discipline, then you can list desirable collaborators in A's documentation and be done with it. There's no hard prevention, so why invent extra hoops?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev mmmmm you made me think... that's correct again, what if you make it protected like the new update? https://repl.it/Mmt5/2

Comment: @DamianLattenero: in this case, `protected` does nothing. The active guard there is `b.class == B`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev but if I call the protected method in C by example, or B, it Breaks, Look! https://repl.it/Mmt5/3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156948/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-damian-lattenero).

Comment: As a piece of general advice, don't say "here's one solution...but here's a better one...". Just give the better one. Inferior solutions are irrelevant and mentioning them only weakens your answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I take your good advice, thanks, I erased almost all... well, long path to travel, long way to learn...

Comment: Subclass is out of question. But IF I can pass the caller to the callee as an argument, this is in fact the simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sergio's answer is correct, however if you really need a hack take a look at the code below:

```
 class CallerClass
  def self.get (c)
     line = c.first.scan(/^.*:(.*):.*/).first.first.to_i
     file = c.first.scan(/^(.*?):/).first.first
     func = c.first.scan(/:in `(.*)?'/).first.first
     fc = File.readlines(file)
     caller_class = nil

     caller_class = '<main>' if func == '<main>'

     line.downto(0) do |it|
       break if caller_class
       caller_class = fc[it].scan(/^\s*class\s+(.*)\s+/).first.first if fc[it] =~ /^\s*class\s+(.*)\s+/
     end
     caller_class
  end

end

class A
  def only_B_can_call_me
     caller_class = CallerClass.get(caller)
     raise "'#{caller_class}' is not an allowed caller" unless caller_class == 'B'
     'called_by_B'
  end
end

class B
  def do_stuff
    A.new.only_B_can_call_me
  end
end

class C
  def do_stuff
    A.new.only_B_can_call_me
  end
end

B.new.do_stuff #called_by_B
C.new.do_stuff #Raises exception
```

OBS. This is a fragile parsing of ruby code using regex, It's a **HACK** you've been warned!!